# Error launching Flask app with error "Failed to find Flask application"

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask). To launch the flask app, I did `python -m flask run` but I repeatedly get the error:

> Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "app". Use "FLASK_APP=app:name to specify one.

I am using a `virtualenv` on a Windows 10 machine

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expected a web server to start and to be able to navigate to localhost `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` where I could view `Hello, World!` on my browser, but that never happened.

Comment: Try running `python <yourfile>.py`.

Comment: Why would expect `python -m flask run` to find your script? Use `env FLASK_APP=your_app.py python -m flask run`.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?  
Go to the folder where app.py is present and run python app.py

Comment: Realized I knew nothing about virtualenv so did my research and fixed a of thing with all my environments.  So not sure what the ultimate solution was because I'm not using the same setup.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of just "flask" use `FLASK_APP=theflaskapp.py`, like what Marco suggested:

```
 env FLASK_APP=theflaskapp.py python -m flask run
```

This should fix it, if not, make sure you are executing the command to run the script in the same directory as it. You should also check if the problem is in flask or not by running "python theflaskapp.py" (In the same directory as the flask app still) and see if it works at all.

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect. May I ask why I needed this on Mac when I had a FLASK_APP var in my .env that wasn't being recognized?

Answer (score 18):

## Reproducing the problem, and fixing it

Hello, I have reproduced the problem
This is the error code:

> Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module
> "src.app". Use "FLASK_APP=src.app:name to specify one.

Steps of reproducing the error:

1. Create a file called **app.py**
2. inside app.py put this code:

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask("abc")

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello, World!'
```

**Or let the file be empty, like this:**

```py
# This is an empty file
# There is no flask application here
```

3. Inside CLI run these commands:

```sh
export FLASK_APP=app.py
flask run
```

4. watch the error appear on the screen

---

## Solution 1 :

1. make the function return the **app**
2. Clearly create a variable called **app** and make it equal to the return value of the function, like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello, World!'
    return app
app = create_app()
```

## Solution 2: Get the app outside of the function:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("abc")

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I would just like to add, the "app = create_app()" should be above the "if __name__ == '__main__'". Otherwise, flask run won't find app

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify what file you want to work with. Try this.

For Windows:

```
set FLASK_APP=app.py
python -m flask run
```

For Mac OS and Linux:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
python -m flask run
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 5):

solution for flask Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
on windows when you tried `set FLASKAPP=appname.py` if your using PowerShell and if get the above error try this

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "filename"
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
Flask run
```

try it if your having trouble launching the flask app.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. It seems to work fine from the command prompt with `python app.py`.  However, it would fail to launch with VS Code Debug.

The trick was to add:

```
server = app.server
```

before calling the `app.run_server()` portion

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to run your app without getting any issue is to create the app then run `python app.py`

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    jsonify
)

# Function that create the app 
def create_app(test_config=None ):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Simple route
    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world(): 
        return jsonify({
           "status": "success",
            "message": "Hello World!"
        }) 
     
    return app # do not foget to return the app

APP = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
    APP.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

On venv and my Windows10 only this syntax works:

```
set FLASK_APP=name_of_file:name_of_var_app
If file is application.py and 'app = Flask(__name__)',
run:
set FLASK_APP=application:app
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another working option is executing this command instead of flask run :

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

I had the same issue and I tried all the mentioned answers here but couldn't work finally this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. The problem is you have to set the environment variable FLASK_APP in current project.

However, I have easiest way to solve this problem. Instead of using `flask run` command you can use `python app.py`.

**"app.py"** is your application entry point.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of the file, I have the same problem. So, I changed the name of the app file and It works for me. At first my app file name is 'socket.py' and I change it to 'app.py'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the python file didn't have execute permissions:

```
chmod a+x app.py
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue! I was running the code in vs code. Installed python extension and after selecting a different python interpreter( in my case 3.10.5 64 bit), got a play button on the top right corner of my vs code interface.
That solved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32788326)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing a super straightforward "try this" suggestion, I'd recommend going straight to the flask source code to where this exception gets thrown, and reverse engineer from there. https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/cli.py#L78-L82

You can open this in your editor by going to the `site-packages/flask/cli.py` file and setting breakpoints around where this error gets thrown, and poke around from there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32798087)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on one of our servers, while our other flask servers will still working fine. Our flask app runs as a installed module. We managed to eventually fix the issue by uninstalling the flask app module, and re-installing it. Which means it was installed incorrectly.

The incorrect way of installing the module was

```bash
pip install -e my_app/
```

And the correct way was

```bash
cd my_app
pip install -e .
```

Answer (score -4):

Try removing the spaces from this line of code, this is what fixed it for me when I had this error:

```
app=Flask(__name__)
```